# How to point TCL procedure to a different directory

Tags: tcl, parameter-passing

I have a procedure which accepts files . I have stored these files in the Tcl\bin folder.Now if i have these files in a different folder , probably a shared folder. How can I point to that specific folder to get these files as input parameters to this procedure?

```
                    proc test {File1 File2 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you're using a relative or absolute file path, you can use the [file](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/file.html) command and its options to detect certain things like access rights. From there you can get away with just using the [open](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/open.html)/[read](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/read.html)/[gets](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/gets.html)/[close](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/close.html) commands to read them in. e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set path "path/to/file/directory/"
set name "file.name"

if {[file exists $path$name]} {
    if {[catch { set handle [open $path$name] }]} {
        puts "Could not open $path$name"
    } else {
        set data [split [read $handle] "\n"]
        close $handle
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the file copy command.   file copy /from/path/file.ext /to/path . I'm getting error while using this.. Should the path be specified with backslash????

Comment: This is a different question for which I'd need to see an updated version of the code. Check that you have read/write access to the files/directories involved. Forward slashes shouldn't be an issue in the path. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Im getting no such file or directory error. I'm trying to use the file copy instead. I'm already handling the reading part of the file..

Comment: Surely it should be: "file copy C:/test.txt C:/Tcl/bin/" -- i.e.: without the /from/ and /to/ prefixes to the source/destination arguments.